# How to get title by navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

To browse from one screen or another, i have this render :

```
 if (this.state.loggedIn) {
            return <Centrale navigation={this.props.navigation} />
        } else {
            return <Accedi navigation={this.props.navigation} />
        }
```

on both screen i can't get the header

```
 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    //console.log("ELENCO " + JSON.stringify(navigation))
    return {
      title: 'ELENCO SVEGLIE',
      headerRight: <View />

    };
  };
```

But if i use the standard navigation ( this.props.navigate("")) , the header work.
Suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setParams` is what you are looking for. `setParams` action allows a screen to change the `params` in the `route`, which is useful for updating the `header buttons and title`. For more link you can refer here.
[here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html)